# FTDI can only open connection if sensor connected before startup

Tags: android, ftdi

I'm using this D2xx driver: http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm

And if I run the application when my sensor is plugged in, I can communicate with the sensor just fine. But if I unplug and replug in the sensor while the application is open, I can see there are 2 devices but openByIndex returns null.
Here is some code.

Manifest parts

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/usb_device_filter" />
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" android:resource="@xml/usb_device_filter" />
```

FTDI portion

```
# c is the main activity, FTDI is a class instantiated from mainactivity
try {
    ftD2xx = D2xxManager.getInstance(c);
} catch (D2xxManager.D2xxException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
# devCount always returns correct amount of sensors
devCount = ftD2xx.createDeviceInfoList(c)

#This returns null if the sensor was unplugged and plugged back in again.
ftDevice = ftD2xx.openByIndex(c, 0);
```

PS. I think it may be a permission error of some kind but I'm not sure how to fix it or how to request permission from the user to use the sensor when it's plugged in while the application is running. Sort of like the equivalent.

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("permission","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v("permission", "Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("permission","Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean ACTION_USB_PERMISSION?